# ssh to the same user but work isolate from each other

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I want to set my ubuntu server that everyone can ssh with the same user and at the same time. But they will work isolate from each other.

e.g. If someone create a file at their home directory, other won't see this file. And when they logout, all their work will be gone.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Not really; that's what separate user accounts are _for_

Comment: I know. But I want to make a public server, so I don't know how many people will ssh to my server and I can't create a new user every time they want to connect to my server.

Comment: @doubleM Why can't you? User accounts are free and can be created and deleted via scripts. But there are a *lot* of security concerns you need to be aware of with running a public shell server! Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: "I know. But I want to..." Well, it can not do what you have described. Are you asking something else? Suggestions on how your goal can be reached? If so, perhaps you should edit your question to include what you specifically want and do not want, what you have tried, and what is not working. [How do I ask a good question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)